# laravel use Request::create and Route::dispatch($request);

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

This is my code

```
$request = Request::create('games/result', 'POST', array(
                 "name"     => Session::get('name'),
                 "score"    => Session::get('score'),
                 "Level"    => Session::get('Level'),
                 "accuracy" => Session::get('accuracy'), 
                 "time"     => Session::get('time'),
                 "bouns"    => Session::get('bouns')
            ));
            var_dump($request->input());
            Request::replace($request->input());
             Route::dispatch($request);
```

The problem is that when its go to the route the inputs are not form the array 
how I can get the inputs from the array

Answer (score 5):

Don't use Request::replace method.

```
$request = Request::create('games/result', 'POST', array(
             "name"     => Session::get('name'),
             "score"    => Session::get('score'),
             "Level"    => Session::get('Level'),
             "accuracy" => Session::get('accuracy'), 
             "time"     => Session::get('time'),
             "bouns"    => Session::get('bouns')
        ));           
$response = Route::dispatch($request);
return $response;
```

Answer (score 1):

This works on Laravel 5.4 - and maybe others too.

In my web controller:

```
public function testground(Request $request)
{   

    $new_request = Request::create(
        'api/customsandbox', 
        'POST', 
        [$request->all(), ['param' => 2]]
    );

    $response = Route::dispatch($new_request);
    dd($response);
}
```

By doing it this way, I didn't need to set the method type (GET, POST, etc) after. I can just set it in the Request::create().

My api route looks like this (have a versioning folder added):

```
Route::post('customsandbox', 'Api\V1\SandboxController@index');
```

Finally my Api's SandboxController index method looks like this:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    return response()->json($request->all());
}
```

That flattens the array and gives me this response:

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:1 [
    "param" => "1"
  ],
  1 => array:1 [
    "param" => 2
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has more than 1 year but for people who arrives here trying to find answers to a similar issue for Laravel 4.2, before to create the request add: `Input::setMethod('post');` and after create the request: `Request::replace($request->input());` The first one forces to use POST method and the second one replaces the current request with the new one created or instanced with the **$request** variable. I think is a bug in this Laravel version.